# Property paths in Sparql

Tags: sparql, rdf

I am posing a Sparql query to Dbpedia endpoint with property paths:

```
select (COUNT(distinct ?s2) AS ?count) WHERE{
?s2 skos:broader{0,2} dbc:Countries_in_Europe
}
```

I want to pose the same query without property paths:

```
select (COUNT(distinct ?s2) AS ?count) (COUNT(distinct ?s1) AS ?count1)  WHERE{
?s2 skos:broader dbc:Countries_in_Europe.
?s1 skos:broader ?s2.
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to get ?s1+?s2 for the second query?
2. For the second query, I expect the sum of the count numbers +1 (dbc:Countries_in_Europe) should be the same with the first query. But they are not. What is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. you're using non-standard SPARQL, i.e. restricting the depth did not made it to the final version, see https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths.

Comment: 2. I guess the first query is supposed to returns sub-categories of the given one up to a depth 2, right? Your second query doesn't do the same. You have to use a UNION of each distance, i.e. one for the direct sub-categories, and one for the other levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're using non-standard SPARQL, i.e. restricting the depth did not make it to the final version, see [the W3C specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths)
2. I guess the first query is supposed to returns sub-categories of the given one up to a depth 2, right? Your second query doesn't do the same. You have to use a UNION of each distance, i.e. one for the direct sub-categories, and one for the other levels.

```sql
    SELECT (COUNT(distinct ?s) AS ?count) WHERE {

    {
     ?s skos:broader dbc:Countries_in_Europe 
    } UNION {
     ?s1 skos:broader dbc:Countries_in_Europe.
     ?s skos:broader ?s1
    }  

    }
```

Note, in your first query you used `{0,2}` which means due to `0` distance the category `dbc:Countries_in_Europe` itself is also part of the result. If you need it, you should add `+1` to the result of the second query.

### Update

As per @JohuaTaylor's comment below, a more compact syntax would be

```sql
SELECT (COUNT(distinct ?s) AS ?count) WHERE {
  ?s skos:broader/skos:broader? dbc:Countries_in_Europe 
}
```

Comment: The `?` path operator would help here.  E.g., the path `broader/broader?` is equivalent to `skos:broader{1,2}`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes, indeed you're right. The question that comes into my mind is more why he/she wants to have the query without property paths.

Comment: In fact, I wanted to do it without property paths to see the difference. Thank you very much for comments and replies.